# Mapping to objects in a lambda function JavaScript - Why doesn't it work without parens?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am running the following in node and can't understand why one works and why the other doesn't. Here I have an array s where s = [1, 2, 3, 4]. I want to map each number to an object. I've been trying this for a long time:

```
s.map(i => {name: i})
```

which returns a list of undefined.

Finally I realized it worked with parenthesis:

```
s.map(i => ({name: i}))
```

This provides the output I want: `[ { name: 1 }, { name: 2 }, { name: 3 }, { name: 4 } ]`

I feel like there is a JavaScript concept I am not understanding. Why does this not work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because `=> {` represents a block function, not returning an object.

Wrapping the object in parentheses does nothing, it simply interrupts that pattern `=> {`, meaning it's interpreted as a concise arrow function rather than a block arrow function, and you can return the object.

So, if you want to return an object, you can either wrap it in parentheses (this is the easiest way):

```
s.map(i => ({ name: i }));
```

Or use a block function:

```
s.map(i => {
  return { name: i };
});
```

(on a side note, you can make your function more concise by passing in `name` as the `map` parameter name:

```
s.map(name => ({ name }));
```

As pointed out by [Tomasz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9791261/tomasz) below, the reason that your first attempt returned a list of `undefined` was because `name:` is the syntax for a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) in JavaScript - and you  were just labelling `name:` then stating the variable `i` - so your code basically looked like this ES5:

```
s.map(function(i) {
  name: i
  // No return so it returns `undefined`
});
```

Comment: Correct, and in that example, the block of code has a label "name" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label. There's no return statement in that block so the returned value is `undefined`

Comment: Yes @Tomasz - just getting round to that!